# Search items list view adapter fragment

Tags: android, listview, search, android-fragments

I have a list view with a custom single item view that shows a title and an image. I had implemented a search bar to search items by title, but when I try to search something I have a nullpointerexception. When I had only the title in the adapter (the image was the same in all the items) it works fine. But now in the new adapter I also change the image in any single item. The error I think is because is use ***Alimentacion.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);***(this line is where I have the nullpointer) to te search function and I only put the title on the search box.. but i don't know how to search only in the title and not in the full adapter..
I have the list view in a fragment.
Mi code is:

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View myInflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_alimentacion, container,false);

    // Set the Text to try this out
    lv = (ListView)myInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    inputSearch = (EditText) myInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
// Listview Data
    String categorias[] = {"1. Huevos y Lacteos", "2. Carnes y Derivados", "3. Pescados y Mariscos", "4. Aceites y grasos", "5. Verduras y hortalizas",
            "6. Frutas", "7. Bebidas",
            "8. Comida Rapida", "9. Pasta y Cereales", "10. Bolleria y Snacks"};
    Integer ImgCategorias[] = {R.drawable.cat1,R.drawable.cat2,R.drawable.cat3,R.drawable.cat4,R.drawable.cat5,R.drawable.cat6
            ,R.drawable.cat7,R.drawable.cat8,R.drawable.cat9,R.drawable.cat10};
   // String Calorias[]= new String [categorias.length];

    // Pass results to ListViewAdapter Class
    CustomList adapter = new
            CustomList(this.getActivity(), categorias, ImgCategorias);


    // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    // OLD ADAPTER
 /*   adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), R.layout.adapter_categorias, R.id.TVTitulo, categorias);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter2); */

    /**
     * Enabling Search Filter
     * */
    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
            Alimentacion.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
                        }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                      int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });

    return myInflatedView;
}

// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If that line returns null pointer exception there's probably a problem with the getFilter function in your adapter which returns a null pointer. You could post that function here so we can have a look at it and debug it and see what's going on in there.